# Selenium XPath: How to click on the Load More button

Tags: selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape off-campus apartment names and addresses for an apartment listing website for universities. My current obstacle is clicking a "Load More" Button in selenium that can appear x number of times per search result. I am new to webscraping, and I was wondering if someone could help me click this button until it is gone, so I then can gather all of the other information using beautifulsoup.

Website:
https://www.rentcollegepads.com/off-campus-housing/mississippi-state/search

Comment: What is your code, what have you tried until now?

Comment: Oh well... just an fyi: that data can be obtained easier, and without selenium overheads. All the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on the element <kbd>Load More</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-success.btn-block > i.fa.fa-refresh"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-success btn-block' and contains(., 'Load More')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hi thanks for this! I used the XPATH option, and it works, but it only click the button once. In this scenario, I need it to click it 2 times, but in other scenarios I might need it to click 10 times for example. Would you know how to do that?

Comment: You have got it all, the `xpath` to `click` with `WebDriverWait` and _and it works_. You can loop it as many times you want, not onlt 2 times but 10, 50, 100 times. If you need help for the loop, feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I used another thread ([How to loop a python action until a button is clickable (selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73546841/how-to-loop-a-python-action-until-a-button-is-clickable-selenium))
and changed it a bit as I had a similar task recently:

you need to add:

```
x_path="//button[@class='btn btn-success btn-block' and contains(., 'Load More')]"
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(5)
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)).perform()

        if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, x_path).is_enabled():
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, x_path).click()
            print('clicked')
        else:
            driver.refresh()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'{e}')
        break
```